# Php curl support

Tags: php, curl

After trying a lot of ways, can you help me to fix this code.

Always returns `{"code":201,"error":"missing user password"}`

```
<?php 
$APPLICATION_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXx"; 
$REST_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/login';

$headers = array(
'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
//option 1
//urlencode('username=xxxxxx'),
//urlencode('password=xxxxxxx'),
);

$curl = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
//option 2 
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'username=xxxxx'); 
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'password=xxxxxxx');

$content = curl_exec($curl); curl_close($curl);

print $content

?>
```

Is a login using PHP

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the specs of that API? Which Content-Type(s) are accepted by that API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass this data as following:

```
$data = array(
   'username' => urlencode('XXXXX'),
   'password' => urlencode('XXXXXXX')
);

// URL-IFY
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

Then pass the data as follows:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kenny pointed out, you'll need to send your POST vars in the following format. I like using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for this:

```
$postData = array(
    'username' => 'Test',
    'password' => 'Tester'
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
```

If you're dealing with HTTP Authentication:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
```

Comment: The 201 response code suggests that this is not HTTP Authentication (but this is just an assumption by me, I already asked for API specs in a comment).